# WordPress adding item to menu deletes post metadata

Tags: database

A client's WordPress site has been behaving strangely recently. I suspect that there are database issues but I'm not sure where to start looking.

The most recent example of strange behaviour:

- Added existing page to existing nav menu in WP backend (Appearance -> Menus)
- All recent changes to database in the form of (I believe) post metadata and plugin data was immediately wiped out.

What could cause such behaviour? I don't even know where to start. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce the strange behavior? If not, that is the place to start. Make a backup, and try to reproduce it. If you know when the behavior is happening you know where to look. Nothing is happening out of the blue, there are one or to variables causing this behavior.

Comment: The only reliable way to reproduce it is to add a submenu item in the WP editor to a predefined nav menu.

Menu code 
    ```register_nav_menus( array(
        'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'xradar' ),
        'mobile-menu' => esc_html__( 'Mobile', 'xradar' )
    ) );```